# Definition of racism inconsistency?

Tags: semantics

For some dictionaries, such as the Oxford one, racism requires that prejudice/discrimination based on the belief that a race is superior/inferior.

But I can't find this requirement anywhere for any definitions of similar words in any dictionary.  For example, "sexism" simply requires prejudice/discrimination based on sex in the Oxford dictionary.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: IMO, the superior/inferior dynamic is fundamental to both examples mentioned. If it is absent from one it is being ignored.

Comment: It's absent from all of the -isms except racism.  Seems odd to me.

Comment: I would have to say this is a product of how huge of an issue racism has been throughout history compared to any other -ism.

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure I follow.  What's the relation between the size of an issue and its definition?

Comment: The various *ism* definitions were "hardened" at different points in history, and hence are apt to be written differently.  (And let's not forget who is writing the dictionaries, either.  Many men will rationalize sexism on the basis that women are "different" -- not "inferior" -- even though their sexist policies relegate women to inferior roles.)

Comment: @Hot Licks Except many racists also use that rationalization.  There's a reason why the slogan for American segregation was "Separate but equal", not "Black people are inferior so lets move them to the back of the bus".

Comment: @pamon - Like I said, consider who writes the dictionaries.

Comment: @HotLicks: I'd think it's more usual for sexist men to not think of themselves as sexist at all, so I disagree with your point regarding "who's writing the dictionaries." I haven't looked it up; is dictionary-writing a primarily male activity?

Comment: The irony here is that assuming a sexist slant in dictionary definitions of sexist would only result if it was a male dominated activity is itself being sexist.  A women may be just as sexist as a man.  Both for and against their own gender.  Let's judge the passage rather than the people.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't find [the superior/inferior] requirement anywhere for any definitions of similar words in **any** dictionary. [...] Is there a reason for this?

Yes, that you haven't looked hard enough.

> **Sexism**
>
> - The belief that one gender is **superior** to the other, especially that men are superior to women. [YD](http://www.yourdictionary.com/sexism), [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sexism)
> - The belief that one sex (usually the male) is naturally **superior** to the other and should dominate most important areas of political, economic, and social life. [DR](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sexism)
> - Refers to the belief or attitude that one gender or sex is **inferior** to, less competent, or less valuable than the other.  [TCDoPCC](https://books.google.com/books?id=j2BdMzokwvAC&pg=PT80&lpg=PT80&dq=dictionary+sexism+inferior&source=bl&ots=SEu4hfgF0l&sig=JEORWgPWyHfXTB4GcDR9EZva-_c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE0Q6AEwB2oVChMIkpDig5_QxwIVRzI-Ch2TdQLA#v=onepage&q=dictionary%20sexism%20inferior&f=false)